# Problems with loading in online libraries to chrome extension - Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm encountering an error where I am unable to access online libraries in my chrome extension. I have specified in the `content_security_policy` manifest key that any resources from `unpkg.com` are to be allowed through but I am still receiving the following error:

`Refused to load the script 'https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`

I know there are many other stackoverflow posts on this issue but I have found none that have worked.

**CHROME EXTENSION**

**HTML**

```html
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

**MANIFEST**

```json
{
    "name": "synthetic-derivatives-interface",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "synthetic derivatives interface",
    "permissions": ["storage","declarativeContent"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://unpkg.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: how odd that it thinks the CSP is `"script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:"` - that's not even the default value for CSP in an extension

Comment: Sounds like you're looking at an old error in `chrome://extensions` page for the old code. Press the clear button there and reload your extension. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Im fairly certain the problem was that every link referenced in CSP needs to have the full URL listed not just the https://example.com part.